# Suppress warnings/errors in Visual Studio 2017 for certain file

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I have a project which is using TypeScript and some external libraries.

I'm searching a way to block all errors and warnings for all .js, .ts, .d.ts etc. files in **node_modules** folder and the folder with other libraries which relative path to the project root is **assets/plugins** . I've tried creating a .eslintignore file with the following content:

```
./node_modules/*
./assets/plugins/*
```

and also

```
./node_modules/**/*.js
./node_modules/**/*.ts
./node_modules/**/*.d.ts
./assets/plugins/**/*.js
./assets/plugins/**/*.ts
./assets/plugins/**/*.d.ts
```

but this didn't work.

Just to recap, I want to block errors and warnings for those files only and remain visible for all other files in the project.

P.S.: All those errors and warnings in .ts and .js files are visible only in Visual Studio 2017 when the project is opened in Visual Studio 2015 there are no errors and warnings.

Comment: I have got the same issue now with Visual Studio 2017 Community and get many warnings from tether.js, I tried 1) .eslintignore and also 2) Options -> Web -> Cody Analysis -> Ignore patterns

Comment: This is why Typescript is losing to flow...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to suppress all warnings for node_modules (both `ECMAScript` and `TypeScript`) you should create an `.eslintignore` file with the following content:

```
**/*.d.ts
**/node_modules/*
**/assets/plugins/*
```

and also create configuration for the typescript compiler (`tsconfig.json` file) in the project root containing the following:

```
{
  "exclude": [
     "node_modules/*",
     "assets/plugins/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Adding an .eslintignore to the root of the project, containing the following, and then restarting VS did the trick for me (for now at least)

```
**/*.d.ts
**/node_modules/*
```

Comment: Restarting VS is important, thanks for that extra detail.

Comment: Where should I put this `.eslintignore` file. I put it where sln file is (not project root), but is not working: `Error TS2304 (TS) Cannot find name 'Map'. Angular (tsconfig project) e:\web\node_modules\@aspnet\signalr-...`

Comment: I've put it with all the other .config-files

Comment: I put my `.eslintignore` file in the project folder and it worked. Developers who are used to using VSCode as opposed to Visual Studio may not know that they also have to add a reference to `.eslintignore` in their `.csproj` file. Simply adding `.eslintignore` file to the folder won't work.

Comment: @burnt1ce How do I add a reference to the .eslintignore file in my .csproj file? I am using VS 2017 15.9.1